# Log4j in Log DSL of Apache Camel Standalone Application

Tags: java, log4j, apache-camel

I tried to configure file `log4.properties` in my standalone application, it shows on console but i am unable to see it in file, following is my code.

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    Main main = new Main(); 
    main.enableHangupSupport(); 
    main.addRouteBuilder(new TestLogRoute()); 
    main.run(); 
} //EO main
```

TestLogRoute Class:

```
public void configure() throws Exception { 
    from("timer://foo?delay=0&period=20000")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Log Configured MT ${body}"); 
}
```

Following is my `log4j.properties` file under `com.my.test.resources`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %5p [%t] - %m%n 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.R.File=d:\\logs\\testlogs.log 
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=15000KB 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] - %m%n
```

EDIT:
In my main class i added the following line, due to this i can see a new log file created in directory but no log get printed in that file:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Comment: What means _see it in file_ ? Is there no output ? Does log4j complains some way ?

Comment: There is typically some printout if there are issues starting/configuring log4j properly. Please check.

Comment: @perencia I mean no log printed in file. No Complains from log4j

Comment: Have you added your log4j.properties to the jar file ?

Comment: @perencia Yes i mentioned path in my thread

Comment: I was referring to the file itself, the log4j.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding slf4j-log4j12.jar in classpath as mentioned here(http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Log4j-in-Camel-Standalone-Application-td5750730.html#a5750828)

Regards,
imran

Comment: Good to know. Can you mark this question as answered?